# Recursion Crash

Tags: c++, recursion

I am writing a program to fill color in a 10(height)*20(width)array. When the recursion meets the box that contains the character # or *, the box wont be colored. The problem is that when i try to perform recursion by setting the current box as center and test its 8 surrounding box, the program crash and stop working. I cant see where I made the mistake.

```
void fillcolor(char fake[HEIGHT][WIDTH], char color, int startx, int starty)
{
        if (fake[starty][startx] != '#' && fake[starty][startx] != '*')
        {
            fake[starty][startx] = color;
            if (startx+1 <= 19 && starty+1 <= 9 && startx-1 >= 0 && starty-1 >= 0)
            {

                fillcolor(fake, color, startx, starty+1);
                fillcolor(fake, color, startx-1, starty);
                fillcolor(fake, color, startx-1, starty+1);
                fillcolor(fake, color, startx+1, starty+1);
                fillcolor(fake, color, startx, starty-1);
                fillcolor(fake, color, startx+1, starty);
                fillcolor(fake, color, startx-1, starty-1);
                fillcolor(fake, color, startx+1, starty-1);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Probably just stack overflow, nothing new. Remove the recursion from your function.

Comment: The classic... just ask yourself if by any chance, for any input, under any circumstances your recursion could re-occur with the same inputs as the first call.

Comment: It will do infinite recursion.  It has other bugs, too.  Try to debug it for a simple 2*2 box (HEIGHT=2, WIDTH=2), and fix all the bugs.

Comment: You ought to understand what meaning of recursion really is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a program that does what you want:

```
void fillcolor_recursive(char (&fake)[HEIGHT][WIDTH], char color, int x, int y, bool(&has_visited)[HEIGHT][WIDTH])
{
    if(((x >= 0 && x < WIDTH )
    &&  (y >= 0 && y < HEIGHT))
    && ! has_visited[y][x])
    {
        has_visited[y][x] = true;

        if(fake[y][x] != '#'
        && fake[y][x] != '*')
        {
            fake[y][x] = color;

            fillcolor_recursive(fake, color, x, y + 1, has_visited);
            fillcolor_recursive(fake, color, x + 1, y, has_visited);
            fillcolor_recursive(fake, color, x, y - 1, has_visited);
            fillcolor_recursive(fake, color, x - 1, y, has_visited);
        }
    }
}

void fillcolor(char (&fake)[HEIGHT][WIDTH], char color, int startx, int starty)
{
    bool has_visited[HEIGHT][WIDTH] = {};

    fillcolor_recursive(fake, color, startx, starty, has_visited);
}
```

The function you posted had a few problems.

It caused a stack overflow because you were not checking whether a specific element had already been looked at.

That is why I split my solution into two functions. `fillcolor` is a non-recursive function, its only purpose is to create an array of booleans that represents whether or not their corresponding elements have been visited.

`fillcolor_recursive` is essentially the function you provided with some changes. In your original function, you made calls to access diagonal elements, that is unnecessary.

You were checking if `startx` and `starty` were out of the bounds incorrectly:

```
if (startx+1 <= 19 && starty+1 <= 9 && startx-1 >= 0 && starty-1 >= 0)
```

This check must be done before you check if `fake[startx][starty]` is equal to `'#'` or `'*'`.

`fillcolor_recursive` should be hidden from the user.